# Oracle : Which column to update ? Complex query

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-update

I have table with 15 columns, 12 columns (January, February, March, ..., December), to fill my table I should know the column to update.

Because the update query depends on the user entry, if he enter 1 I should update January and so...

I would like to know if it's possible to do that or not ?

I have 3 queries :

1. I collect data from many tables to calculate value for one year, one month one sens(Import/Export and product)
2. I put the result in another intermediate table with only sens, year, month and value
3. third query is to update another table with the intermediate table

This third table who have (January, February, March,..) columns

Thanks

Comment: `if he enter 1 i should update January and so...` how user will enter 1 for the value to be updated?

Comment: whether you are taking values in procedure and then based on these values you are updating table?

Comment: only one user who will enter the number

Comment: sir that is what I was asking how?
while execute the update statement whether he will put 1?
If yes then he could directly write column name in place of giving extra value 1 or 2.

Comment: What I am asking is that user will have to provide some values like primary key value (for what he want to update table) and the value to be updated( if user enter 1 then we need to update this value into january column) so these value and the entry value (1,2 and so on) how he is providing?

Comment: OK, this is a procedure that will be run as a oracle job, and according to the month in previous query we update the appropriate column (January, February,...) in another table i hope it's clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got there is a bad database design. The best cource to take would be to normalise those columns into a single column with an additional column to indicate the month.

However, you can control the column that is updated with a case statement.

```
update
  my_table
set
  january_col  = case when column_to_update = 1 then new_value else january_col  end,
  february_col = case when column_to_update = 2 then new_value else february_col end,
  march_col    = case when column_to_update = 3 then new_value else march_col    end,
  ... etc
where
  ...
```

Comment: yes maybe you are right but the query is so complex (start with query to do some update)

Answer (score 0):

[after this clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646149/oracle-which-column-to-update-complex-query?noredirect=1#comment23942944_16646149)

suppose we have procedure where we are getting user entry in variable p_user_in and the desired value in parameter p_val.

I guess you are providing primary key value also to procedure(I am taking one column col1 as Primary key to table) and this value we are getting in p_prim_val.

then you can use the following update statement to update your table accordingly -

```
update table_name 
set  January = case when p_user_in = 1 then p_val else January end,
 February = case when p_user_in = 2 then p_val else February end,
 March = case when p_user_in = 3 then p_val else March end,
 April = case when p_user_in = 4 then p_val else April end,
 May = case when p_user_in = 5 then p_val else May end,
 June = case when p_user_in = 6 then p_val else June end,
 July = case when p_user_in = 7 then p_val else July end,
 August = case when p_user_in = 8 then p_val else August end,
 September = case when p_user_in = 9 then p_val else September end,
 October = case when p_user_in = 10 then p_val else October end,
 November = case when p_user_in = 11 then p_val else November end,
 December = case when p_user_in = 12 then p_val else December end
where col1 = p_prim_val
```

Comment: Thank's a lot it's the same like David say before.

Comment: yes @devosJava I had seen after I posted. This is correct approach and you can build you logic based on this.

Comment: Sorry @patrik garg but when i execute my code it work but only for the last update. because i'm working in loop

Comment: @devosJava what is your Loop condition and how you are looping for this?